# Number of ways to distribute $N/2$ blue and $N/2$ red balls over $N$ positions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I have read this one: [How many 7-digit even numbers less than 3000000 can be formed using all the digits 1,2,2,3,5,5,6?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821/permutations-with-identical-items) which sounds like a duplicate, but I couldn't easily apply the answer to my question (in other words, I didn't get the answer, sadly)

So here is my question:

Let's say I have `N` balls of 2 colors, `N/2` of each, e.g. 6 balls, 3 blue ones and 3 red ones.

```
(B, B, B, R, R, R)
```

Is there a formula that calculates the number of permutations that ignores similar items?

examples of the 20 permutations of the above (thanks to Scala's permutations method on collection, didn't do it by hand :))

```
(B, B, B, R, R, R)
(B, B, R, B, R, R)
(B, B, R, R, B, R)
(B, B, R, R, R, B)
(B, R, B, B, R, R)
(B, R, B, R, B, R)
(B, R, B, R, R, B)
(B, R, R, B, B, R)
(B, R, R, B, R, B)
(B, R, R, R, B, B)
(R, B, B, B, R, R)
(R, B, B, R, B, R)
(R, B, B, R, R, B)
(R, B, R, B, B, R)
(R, B, R, B, R, B)
(R, B, R, R, B, B)
(R, R, B, B, B, R)
(R, R, B, B, R, B)
(R, R, B, R, B, B)
(R, R, R, B, B, B)
```

I'm sure the solution is simple, but it has been years since my last statistics and probablilty class and I fee a little brain dead.

Please forgive me if this was answered over and over again here in different forms, I couldn't find a "for dummies" answer that I managed to apply to this case (perhaps I didn't look long enough...)

Comment: Write the number of permutations as if everything were distinct. For each group of indistinct items of size $m$, divide by $m!$.  In your example, this gives $6!/(3!\cdot3!)$.

Comment: Oh, right! thanks

Comment: Another way to look at it: You have $N$ places. You have $\binom{N}{B}$ choices for the places where blue balls go. Then you have $N_B$ places left, and $\binom{N-B}{R}$ choices where to put the red balls. Then $\binom{N-B-R}{G}$ choices where to place the green balls ... Multiply and simplify, you get $\frac{N!}{B!\cdot R!\cdot G!\cdot \dotsb}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 20:

There are $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ ways to distribute the 3 `R`'s over the $6$ positions. Given such a distribution, the 3 `B`'s must go to the remaining 3 positions.

By this reasoning, you get $\binom{N}{N/2}$ ways in your more general setting.